# I have a 5th gen iPad on iOS13.1.2 and the Wifi will not toggle on

Tags: ipad

Wifi will not toggle off and I have already reset network settings and wiped device. It is not the antenna because Bluetooth is working.

Comment: They are very probably different antennae. Hardware failure is a definite possibility, try a repair shop.

Comment: What happens when you click on WiFi from Settings?